# How to add an overall file Header row above the column header row in an SSIS created CSV file

Tags: csv, ssis, header

The vendor requires that I add header row in my CSV file just above the column header row. It would look something like this pattern(see below). All I need to do now is add an overall header row at the top of my extract. I am wondering what the easiest way to do that is?

001|Mercy Hospital|P|2019-09-16 08:56:31

ID number | Name        | Room  | Age      | Dx       | Attending MD

11111     | John Doe    | 101   | 71       | C9236    |  Who

22222     | Jane Smith  | 102   | 44       | C11345   |  No

33333     | M. Mouse    | 103   | 66       | Ce3456   |  Phibes

Answer (score 0):

In the your destination component, in the `Flat File Connection`, check the option `Column names in the first data row`.

Then in Advanced, you can provide the name you want to each column  manually.

Finally, in `Flat File Destination`, you can re-do the mapping of the columns.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do this. I think I have this already if I am understanding you,  since I already have column headers in the extract. I was hoping to place a new header row above the column headers. The new header row would not be related to the columns at all but would act as sort of Title to the extract.